# Group by cause double records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have TWO table:

TABLE ALBUM

| id | AlbumDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Siamo Qui |
| 2 | Safari |
| 3 | Perfetto |

TABLE SONG

| id | idAlbum | SongDescription | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AlbaChiara | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | Gabri | 40 |
| 3 | 2 | ombellico | 50 |
| 4 | 2 | I love you baby | 10 |
| 5 | 3 | cose della vita | 60 |
| 6 | 3 | aurora | 20 |

The tables are linked via Song.idAlbum and Album.id

Now I have to make a query that extrapolates the song that lasts longer for each album, displaying the name of the song as well

By doing this query I have duplicate records, what is the best approach to eliminate duplicate records?

```
SELECT MAX(Duration) as Duration
,A.AlbumDescription
,C.SongDescription
FROM Album A
left JOIN Canzone C ON A.id = C.idAlbum
GROUP BY A.AlbumDescription, C.SongDescription
```

Result:

| Duration | AlbumDescription | SongDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Siamo Qui | AlbaChiara |
| 60 | Perfetto | Cose della vita |
| 40 | Siamo Qui | Gabri |
| 10 | Safari | I love you baby |
| 20 | Perfetto | aurora |
| 50 | Safari | ombellico |

What would i expect

| Duration | AlbumDescription | SongDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | Perfetto | Cose della vita |
| 40 | Siamo Qui | Gabri |
| 50 | Safari | ombellico |

Comment: `Group by` cannot in any way cause double rows, that is not what it does. Probably you expected it to remove double rows, and it did not do that.  That is an entire different thing

Answer (score 2):

We can use `RANK()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.AlbumDescription, c.SongDescription, c.Duration,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY c.Duration DESC) rnk
    FROM Album a
    INNER JOIN Canzone c ON c.idAlbum = a.id
)

SELECT Duration, AlbumDescription, SongDescription
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that if you don't expect or care about the possibility for two or more songs on the same album having the same maximum length, then you may also use `ROW_NUMBER` above instead of `RANK`.  As written, the above would return all songs on a given album tied for being the longest.

We can write a shorter version of the above using a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES a.AlbumDescription, c.SongDescription, c.Duration
FROM Album a
INNER JOIN Canzone c ON c.idAlbum = a.id
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY c.Duration DESC);
```

But note that this probably will not perform as well as the first version, and it should only be used when you don't care much about performance but more about code brevity.

Comment: thank you very much, I knew this approach I wanted to know if it was correct or there were different or shorter solutions.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, on SQL Server we can write a shorter solution.  But that does not necessarily mean it will perform the same as my first version.

Comment: Why do you use CTE, I don't get the same result by doing: select * from 
 (
    SELECT a.AlbumDescription, c.SongDescription, c.Duration,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY c.Duration DESC) rnk
    FROM Album a
    INNER JOIN Canzone c ON c.idAlbum = a.id
) T

Comment: The code in your comment is not what appears in my answer.  Both versions should be producing the same result set (though you may have to subquery the second version and order by the album).

Comment: What I meant instead of using the CTE in the head put directly select * from (select ...) since it works anyway what need is there to use the CTE? why is it faster?

Comment: The CTE (common table expression) is needed by itself, or a subquery, because it takes one pass over the tables to assign a rank to every record.  Once we have that intermediate result, we can subquery the CTE and restrict to only rank one records.  My second version sort of gets around this, at the cost of losing some performance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use group by with both AlbumDescription, SongDescription it makes 2 groups.
Because (Siamo Qui,AlbaChiara) and (Siamo Qui,Gabri) are different. As you want to find the song with the longest duration you should group it by AlbumDescription. You might want to use album id.

```
SELECT MAX(Duration) as Duration
,A.AlbumDescription
,C.SongDescription
FROM Album A
left JOIN song C ON A.id = C.idAlbum
GROUP BY A.AlbumDescription;
```

this query returns:

| Duration | AlbumDescription | SongDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | Perfetto | Cose della vita |
| 40 | Siamo Qui | Gabri |
| 50 | Safari | ombellico |

Or you can use

```
SELECT FROM album as A 
LEFT JOIN song AS S on a.id = s.idAlbum 
WHERE S.duration == (SELECT max(duration) 
                     FROM song WHERE idAlbum = S.idAlbum);
```

both return the same result.

These are the table in data in case anyone wants to try;

```
CREATE TABLE album
(
 id INTEGER,
 albumDescription TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE song
(
  id INTEGER,
  idAlbum INTEGER REFERENCES album(id),
  songDescription TEXT,
  duration INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO album VALUES
(1, 'Siamo Qui'),(2, 'Safari'),(3, 'Perfetto');

INSERT INTO song VALUES
(1,1, 'AlbaChiara',30),
(2,1, 'Gabri',40),
(3,2, 'ombellico',50),
(4,2, 'I love you baby',10),
(5,3, 'cose della vita',60),
(6,3, 'aurora',20);
```

Comment: in the first query there is an error on the group by, the second query works

Comment: I tried https://datawithdev.com/sql-playground online playground. It may not work in real life.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put aggregation on sone description like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Duration) as Duration
,A.AlbumDescription
,MAX(C.SongDescription) as SongDescription
FROM Album A
left JOIN Canzone C ON A.id = C.idAlbum
GROUP BY A.AlbumDescription
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. If you use `MAX` with SongDescription nothing says you will get correct song description.. You will get highest value in that field for given AlbumDescription which can return all kind of things. I.E. if album1 has Song1 and Song2. Durations are 30 and 20 for given songs you would get row Album1 Song2 30 (when it should be Album1 Song1 30

Comment: I think the best solution in alternative all cte is:  SELECT FROM album as A 
LEFT JOIN song AS S on a.id = s.idAlbum 
WHERE S.duration = (SELECT max(duration) 
                     FROM song WHERE idAlbum = S.idAlbum);